# How to open a window in background without letting it get the focus?

Tags: window-manager, window, focus

#### Scenario:

1. Open a program that is starting slowly
2. Not wait for it to open, and switch to other window/task. For e.g. selecting some files in a directory to delete
3. While I am working focused on other task (selecting files) that program, after a few seconds, opens and covers everything

#### The desired behavior:

Do not open on top of all windows and distract me while I am working on other task, instead display a notification in side panel so I will open that window when I'll want (when I'll finish my current task)

[image: launcher with highlighted icon]

#### What happens instead:

That program doesn't care what I am doing at the moment, it just opens rude in my face and covers everything.

---

This looks like a very minor problem, but it happens to me almost every day and already started to annoy me.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with [gdevilspie](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/)

[image: configuration screenshot]

Comment: This is not what I was looking for and it's useless. Instead of being opened in background and to appear active in sidebar http://i.stack.imgur.com/ozJ27.png here's what happens: I click to open PhpStorm, then I switch to terminal and work there, then PhpStorm is fast: opened -> focused -> minimized, and the focus from terminal is lost, and I have to click on terminal icon to get focus and continue writing, this is the same what I was doing before installing gdevilspie. It will be cool to have an option/checkbox in Ubuntu System Settings "Start programs in background"